# Take a photo on iPhone and overlay text permanently before saving in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2

I have just started with programming. I am trying to overlay text on an image taken with the iPhone prior to saving the image. I have found bits of code that look promising but nothing that does the job specifically, and no posts that answer the question specifically. This is my code to take an image. Without the attempt at overlaying the text I know it takes a photo.

```
@IBAction func handleShutterButton(sender: UIButton) {
    cameraController.captureStillImage { (image, metadata) -> Void in
        self.view.layer.contents = image
        var project = "ProjectX"
        var camNumber = "c01"
        let timestamp = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .MediumStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle)
        let overlay = "\(project) \(camNumber) \(timestamp)"
        self.overlayText(overlay, inImage: UIImage(named: image)!, atPoint: CGPointMake(20, 20)) // This is where it fails
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    }
}
```

And this is the function I'm using for overlaying the text.

```
func overlayText(drawText: NSString, inImage: UIImage, atPoint:CGPoint)->UIImage{

    // Setup the font specific variables
    let textColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    let textFont: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 12)!

    //Setup the image context using the passed image.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(inImage.size)

    //Setups up the font attributes that will be later used to dictate how the text should be drawn
    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
    ]

    //Put the image into a rectangle as large as the original image.
    inImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height))

    // Creating a point within the space that is as big as the image.
    let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(atPoint.x, atPoint.y, inImage.size.width, inImage.size.height)

    //Now Draw the text into an image.
    drawText.drawInRect(rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    // Create a new image out of the images we have created
    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    // End the context now that we have the image we need
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //And pass it back up to the caller.
    return newImage
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made changes in your code.. Try this..

```
@IBAction func handleShutterButton(sender: UIButton) {

    cameraController.captureStillImage { (image, metadata) -> Void in
        self.view.layer.contents = image
        var project = "ProjectX"
        var camNumber = "c01"
        let timestamp = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: .MediumStyle, timeStyle: .ShortStyle)
        let overlay = "\(project) \(camNumber) \(timestamp)"
        var changedImage : UIImage = self.overlayText(overlay, inImage: image, atPoint: CGPointMake(20, 20)) // This is where it fails
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(changedImage, nil, nil, nil);
    }
}
```

Comment: Still get the same error - Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage' to expected argument type 'String'. Oops. I should have added the error in the original post.

Comment: I had to make the vars lets for Swift 2 but other than that this works perfectly! Thank you Ashish.